# PHP 301 redirect giving a 302 instead

Tags: php, redirect, seo

On Sept 1st, I did a 301 on my web page: http://www.gameaudio101.com/toolbox.php and it redirects to http://www.gameaudio101.com/jobs.php

The problem is that over time, the new page was never indexed.  The original still shows up in google search.  Both pages are identical but the old one has this at the top:

```
<? 
Header( "http://www.gameaudio101.com/toolbox.php 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.gameaudio101.com/jobs.php" ); 
?>
```

Should that be the ONLY code on the page?  Please help a non-coder!

Answer (score 7):

Your first header is incorrect. It should be

```
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.gameaudio101.com/jobs.php");
exit;
```

Or this

```
header("Location: http://www.gameaudio101.com/jobs.php", true, 301);
exit;
```